# Understanding parsec type annotations

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) to parse some source code into an AST. I recently turned on the `-Wall` and `-W` options in order to catch "suspicious" code, and it is complaining about many of [the parsec-related top-level functions in this file](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/3361f152da6e0bd93034a8367d079a30be35b451/lib/Docvim/Parse.hs) not having explicit type extensions.

## Example 1

```
vimL = choice [ block
              , statement
              ]
```

The inferred type here is:

```
vimL :: ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Node
```

So, if I add that annotation, the compiler complains about not having access to `Data.Functor.Identity.Identity`, which means I have to `import` it:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
```

And if I do that, I can simplify the type annotation to:

```
vimL :: ParsecT String () Identity Node
```

and the compiler will still accept it. But it's still not something I understand very deeply.

## Example 2

```
link = Link <$> (bar *> linkText <* bar)
  where
    bar      = char '|'
    linkText = many1 $ noneOf " \t\n|"
```

The inferred type here is:

```
link :: forall u.
         ParsecT String u Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Node
```

But I can't use that unless I also use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

Note that I can dispense with that if I drop the `forall`. Both of these work:

```
link :: ParsecT String u Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Node
link :: ParsecT String u Identity Node
```

## Example 3

```
string' s = mapM_ char' s >> pure s <?> s
```

This one's inferred type is:

```
string' :: forall s u (m :: * -> *).
            Stream s m Char =>
             [Char] -> ParsecT s u m [Char]
```

In order to use that one, I need both:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
```

But again, if I drop the `forall` I can simplify the type to the following and the compiler still accepts it:

```
string' :: Stream s m Char => [Char] -> ParsecT s u m [Char]
```

Not very simple, though. Going further and dropping the constaint:

```
string' :: [Char] -> ParsecT s u m [Char]
```

I get:

```
No instance for (Stream s m Char) arising from a use of ‘char'’
```

I thought:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

might get me out of that, but it does not.

## Questions

These mostly go over my head, so I don't want to blindly copy-paste the inferred type signatures in without gaining some more insight first. Can anybody shed some light on what these mean, what would be the best practices for annotating parsec-heavy code, what does the `forall` buy me if it can be omitted without causing any compiler errors, and whether there are any aliasing tricks that I can employ to make these more readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert with `parsec`, so I'll let someone else do the heavy lifting if they want to explain the types, but here are some thoughts:

Generally packages try to export more friendly type synonyms. In this case, you can use

```
type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Identity -- in Text.Parsec.Prim
type Parser = Parsec String ()         -- in Text.Parsec.String
```

so that gets you `vimL :: Parser Node`, which should make more sense - it is a parser that can be run on a `String` to produce a `Node`.

`forall` gets *you* very little in this context, which is why there are friendly type synonyms available, which you should use. However, I'm willing to bet that in its own guts `parsec` makes heavy use of higher-rank types, which cannot be expressed without the `forall` and this is why the signatures GHC proposes to you have an explicit `forall`.

(Briefly, `forall x. <something-with-x>` is the same as `<some-thing-with-x>` but if you have the `forall` in the middle of the signature, things get much nastier.)

## EDIT

Some stuff on `parsec` ([from the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.1)). The type `ParsecT s u m a` represents the most general parser possible. Reading the comments in [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.1/docs/src/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#State) helps.

- `s` describes the stream type. A parser in the abstract sense takes a sequence of symbols and converts them into some structured output form.
- `a` is the type of the output form.
- `u` is the user state type. `parsec` already keeps track of some state information (like your position in the text so that it can give you back a meaningful parse error message) so it makes sense to let the user package in some state they would like carried along (there is an example of this in [2.12 Advanced: User State](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf))
- `m` is the underlying monad in which things are being run. I think this part will be evident iff you grok monads...

Then, a couple special cases arise:

- Taking `m = Identity` means that we don't need a monadic context of execution. (The `Parsec s u a` type synonym is for this case.)
- Taking `u = ()` means that we don't need to hold any state information.
- Taking `s = String` means our input (stream) will be a string. (Combined with the other two options above, that is what the `Parser a` type synonym is for.)

Finally, `string' :: forall s u (m :: * -> *). Stream s m Char => [Char] -> ParsecT s u m [Char]` means that the output is a `String = [Char]`, and the user state, monadic context, and input can be anything - provided they satisfy some conditions, hence the `Stream s m Char` constraint.

That constraint [`Stream s m t`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.1/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Stream) means that you must be able to "unfold" the stream input type `s` into an `m (Maybe (t,s))`. The `m` part means that this unfolding can occur in a monadic context, the `Maybe` part deals with the fact that you can unfold only as long as you have input, the `t` is token you are taking off the front of the stream, and `s` is the remainder of the stream. Finally, the type of the stream `s` has to uniquely identify the type of the token `t` coming out, so there is a functional dependency `s -> t`.

Comment: This is very helpful. `string' :: forall s u (m :: * -> *). Stream s m Char => [Char] -> ParsecT s u m [Char]` became `string' :: String -> Parser String`, and most of the others became `Parser Node`, `Parser String` or `Parser ()`.